# SWI Prolog query

Tags: prolog

```
:- dynamic plop/2
add(Var):-
    retract(plop(Var,X))->
    (X = X+1, assert(plop(Var,X)));
    (assert(plop(Var,1))).
```

So if i call add(y). it will create plop(y,1) but when i call add(y). again why wont it add one to the so it will be plop(y,2)

Comment: Please don't change the question entirely. If you have a new question, ask a new question using the `Ask Question` button.

Answer (score 6):

Because there is no X that would fulfill this relationship: `X = X+1`, and the rule fails. Try `Y is X+1, assert(plop(Var,Y))` there instead.